# How to not proceed serialization of whole object if one or more required fields have null value?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, pojo

I have next big JSON...

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  ...
  "field100": "value100",
}
```

...and appropriate POJO

```
@Builder
@Data
public class BigJsonDto{
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    private String field100;
}
```

Let's say all fields are required and nullable except `field1` that can't have a `null` value.

So I want to tell Jackson (or another way) stop serialization if one or more required fields have `null` value, rather than just ignore it (with `@JsonInclude`). How can I reach it?

It would be nice if it's possible to use built-in `ObjectMapper`.

I tried to use `@JsonProperty(required = true)` annotation but as I can see this annotation is used in deserialization. So in this case, I got required fields with null values.

Comment: In the question, you've emphasized that you're concerned about `serialization` into JSON, not `deserialization`. The currently accepted solution does validation during `deserialization`. If that's want you're really needed - fine. I've provided a possible solution for the case of `serialization` into JSON as required according to your original problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add the [`@NonNull`](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) annotation to the field you require to not be null. Then you can try to handle the exception whenever you build the `BigJsonDto` object. For example the code below will throw the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: field1 is marked non-null but is null
    at BigJsonDto.<init>(StackOverflowQuestion.java:21)
    at BigJsonDto$BigJsonDtoBuilder.build(StackOverflowQuestion.java:21)
    at StackOverflowQuestion.main(StackOverflowQuestion.java:16)
```

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;

public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        var output = mapper.writeValueAsString(
                BigJsonDto.builder()
                        // uncomment this line to not throw exception
                        //.field1("a")
                        .field2("b")
                        .field100("c").build());
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}

@Builder
@Data
class BigJsonDto {
    @NonNull
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field100;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm so obsessed with Jackson annotations that I completely forgot about others.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prevent an invalid POJO from being serialized you can create a *custom serializer* by extending `JsonSerializer`.

For that, you would need to override `serialize()` method.

```
public class BigJsonDtoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigJsonDto> {
    
    public static final Predicate<BigJsonDto> IS_NOT_VALID =
        dto -> Stream.of(dto.getField1(), // add as many fields as you need
                         dto.getFieldN())
            .anyMatch(Objects::isNull);

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigJsonDto value, JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    
        // Serialization fails
        if (IS_NOT_VALID.test(value)) throw new JsonGenerationException("BigJsonDto instance is not valid", gen);
        
        // Serialization succeeds (we need to provide the value of every field to JsonGenerator)
        gen.writeString(value.getField1());
        gen.writeString(value.getField2());
        gen.writeString(value.getField3());
        // Et cetera
        gen.writeString(value.getFieldN());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<BigJsonDto> handledType() { // needed ONLY if registered as part of module
        return BigJsonDto.class;
    }
}
```

Then you can register the serializer through the `using` attribute of the annotation `@JsonSerialize` applied on the top of your class.

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonSerialize(using = BigJsonDtoSerializer.class)
public static class BigJsonDto {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String fieldN;
}
```

Or you can register the serializer (or multiple serializers) globally by including it into a custom module (as described in the [Jackson's documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers#with-jackson-17-and-above)). This way also require `handledType()` to be overridden in each these serializers. If you're using Spring Boot, to register the module you can place in the Spring's Context as a Bean, or do it manually (if you're not using Spring in your project) via `ObjectMapper.registerModule()`. Annotation `@JsonSerialize` would not be needed in this case.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule mySerializationModule = new SimpleModule(
        "MySerializationModule",
        new Version(1, 0, 0,
            "module-description",
            "groupId",
            "artifactId"
        ),
        Map.of(),                           // deserializers
        List.of(new BigJsonDtoSerializer()) // serializers
    );

mapper.registerModule(mySerializationModule);
```

*Usage example:*

```
String sourceJson = """
    {
        "field1" : null,
        "field2" : "Bob",
        "field3" : "Carol",
        "fieldN" : "N"
    }
    """;
    
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // for simplisity let's assume you chosen annotate the class with @JsonSerialize instead of registing the module
    
BigJsonDto dto = mapper.readValue(sourceJson, BigJsonDto.class);
String resultingJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(dto); // <- this line would fale because field1 is null
```